# Quarkus - extension include 3rd party ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, quarkus

If I follow [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#http-filters-and-interceptors) I can add a ContainerRequestFilter and it gets picked up by Quarkus and runs as expected. However, I'm writing an extension to take advantage of a ContainerRequestFilter written by another team. I'm unsure of how to get Quarkus to use this filter. I've tried adding it as an AdditionalBeanBuildItem

```
@BuildStep
public void producer(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans) {    
  additionalBeans.produce(AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(3rdPartyFilter.class));
}
```

But this doesn't work and the filter doesn't run on requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at how other extensions do this, for example how the `quarkus-smallrye-opentracing` does it.

Essentially all you need is to add a JAX-RS DynamicFeature in the `runtime` module of your application.

```
@Provider
public class QuarkusSmallRyeTracingStandaloneVertxDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(MyFilter.class);
    }

    public static class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something special way to get bean injected to a Filter that is registered this way? I am trying to inject some beans but they are showing up as null in the Filter. However, if I inject those same beans into a REST resource class they are injected just fine.

Comment: You can't inject into the Filter using `@Inject`, however you can use `Arc.container().instance(...)` to obtain whatever bean you need

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @geoand's answer, I think you also need to add a @BuildStep in the deployment part of your extension.

```
import io.quarkus.resteasy.common.spi.ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem;

class MyProcessor {

    @BuildStep
    ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem createOpentracingFilter() {
        return new ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem(MyFilter.class.getName());
    }
}
```